# Turn off URI's in Web API

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I'm only concerned with data, and do not need the various URI paths returned by the Web API.  I'm concerned with performance, so is there anyway to turn this off?

example:

```
   "outgoing_relationships":"http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/0/relationships/out",
   "labels":"http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/0/labels",
   "data":{  
      // I only want this information.
   },
   "traverse":"http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/0/traverse/{returnType}",
   "all_typed_relationships":"http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/0/relationships/all/{-list|&|types}",
   "self":"http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/0",
   "property":"http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/0/properties/{key}",
   "properties":"http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/0/properties",
   "outgoing_typed_relationships":"http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/0/relationships/out/{-list|&|types}",
   "incoming_relationships":"http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/0/relationships/in",
   "extensions":{  

   },
   "create_relationship":"http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/0/relationships",
   "paged_traverse":"http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/0/paged/traverse/{returnType}{?pageSize,leaseTime}",
   "all_relationships":"http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/0/relationships/all",
   "incoming_typed_relationships":"http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/0/relationships/in/{-list|&|types}"
```

Comment: i think no, i also wanted to do this but the answer was to implement my own rest api with only the specific data needed. but this was a year ago, maybe smthng has changed since that

Answer (score 2):

I would just use the [Cypher HTTP Endpoint](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/rest-api-cypher.html). This lets you trim the returned data by adjusting what you return from the query.

```
match n return n limit 1
```

Will give you a full Neo4j REST node representation back, while

```
match n return n.name limit 1
```

will just get you the `name` string. Also, Cypher is much more powerful than the rest of the REST API.

Comment: Hmm this would *almost* be suitable if I was able to do something like return n.*.  But I will not always know the exact schema of every node.

Comment: if you just return `n` it will return all data on `n` as a map.